# FindBy('myvar' => $array) not working with mongoDbOdm in Symfony3?

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-odm, symfony

I have filled a mongodb-collection with the following values (identifer = `myvar`):

```
array (size=10)
  0 => string 'B00LHILHS8' (length=10)
  1 => string 'B00WSCCMV8' (length=10)
  2 => string 'B00MA15OK8' (length=10)
```

However - `findBy(['myvar' => 'B00LHILHS8'])` returns the document as wanted. But `findBy(['myvar' => ['B00LHILHS8', 'B00WSCCMV8']])` returns an `empty` result.

I am not sure, if this is right. As the [Doctrine Manual - Working with objects - By Simple Conditions](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions) mentions, that it should be possible to pass an array for the `findBy()` method.

Should i use the query-builder instead?

Comment: myvar is a tag and B00LHILHS8 is a value??

Comment: @Cuchu - Yes. I have a document with severals field and `myvar` is one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use doctrine-mongodb-odm with Conditional Operators [[link]](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/query-builder-api.html#conditional-operators)

try:

```
$qb = $dm->createQueryBuilder('Entity')
    ->field('myvar')->in(array('B00LHILHS8', 'B00WSCCMV8'));
```

Comment: I use doctrine but with mysql and mongodb with php api.

Comment: and then $query = $qb->getQuery(); $result = $query->execute();

Comment: Thanks, working with the `QueryBuilder` helped me - but the problem is, that `findBy()` seems not work with Doctrine and MongoDB properly. With mysql it does.

Comment: findBy use array(field1 => value1, field2 => value2)

Comment: @Roman MongoDB will happily hold array value in the document so effectively your query is asking for `myvar` with an array as its value - this is perfectly valid in MongoDB world :)